# Anchors in CodeIgniter like in Ruby on Rails

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, anchor

in Ruby on Rails i can generate links like `<%= link_to 'Name', :controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name' %>`.
This alos works when i have changed the route for this url.

Is it possible to get something like this in CodeIgniter with the `anchor` when i have defined custom routes?

I hope it is understandable ;)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your codeigniter project configuration, you can create simple html links with href attribute set to `/index.php/controller/action` or `/controller/action`. I am not sure if there are any link helpers present.

Comment: Yes i know that i can create my html links like this `<?php echo anchor('/controller/action`, 'My link', array('class' => 'some_class'); ?>`
But i want set my links global, that i can use the new route

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.. Can't you use html links or anchor function to link to custom routes? I think you can. I am sorry if my codeigniter is a little rusty.

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom routes set in application/config/routes.php then they won't be executed by the anchor function, you will have to extend the URL helper and redefine this function by passing your custom routes. Hope that helps

Comment: Obviously they won't be executed, because `anchor()` just prints out a link.  BUT, if the link contains a custom route, it WILL follow it.